# How do i calulate Image Fidelity using this equation?

Tags: python, matlab, steganography

[image: Image Fidelity]

Hi, how do i calculate image fidelity from this Mathematical Equation? The equation was taken from
"A novel method for digital image steganography based on a new three-dimensional chaotic map"

Comment: You have marked this as both python and matlab. Which one are you interested in? I assume that `P(i, j)` is the pixel at position (i, j), and `S(i, j)` is the stego image pixel at the same position. It seems like a very straigtforward arithmetic computation, so *what* is tripping you up?

Comment: Oh ok.. the document did not give any reference paper for this formula